# switchable engine water pump, an improvement?

Tags: engine, cooling, water, pump

Some engines nowadays have a switchable water pump that can be turn off at cold start, like the ones found on some Volkswagen diesel engines.
Those a mechanical pump that can be disabled at cold start in order to shorten warming up time.
At least, that is the marketing claim.
Those engine still have a regular thermostat.

Any idea, if those pumps really make a difference concerning warming up time ?

Comment: They will make a difference for sure when they fail to kick in...

Comment: exactly! that's why I'm wondering if the benefits outweigh the cons.

Comment: The pump circulates the coolant throughout the system whether cold (internal to the engine) or hot (through the entire system), with a little help from the thermostat. The engine gets hot at certain spots within the engine sooner than others. If you are circulating the coolant when the engine is cold, I would think you'd run the risk of overheating in these locations. The risk warpage due to uneven heating would seem to me to be quite a real scenario without the coolant pump running. I'm not sure what it would really gain you?

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 the gain? well, that IS the theme of this post. you can look at http://pics3.tdiclub.com/data/517/820433_EA288.pdf as an example.  to avoid hot spot, the engine head has its own cooling circuit and pump. only the block is switched off.

Comment: So it really doesn't turn off. Seems like something more to break and be replaced. Why mess with something which works.

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 something more to break, it certainly is! not to mention the cost, $400 MSRP for an engine water pump.

Comment: Cross posted on Engineering : https://engineering.stackexchange.com/q/34979/10902

Comment: Ah nothing like German engineering!